# Reading a file and adding to a list once it reaches an empty line

Tags: python

I have a method which reads a file as described below and adds each entry of first name, last name up until the specified size into a list and returns the list.

The file looks something like this:

```
Smith
John
newline
Jeff
Johnny
newline
```

where we have first name, last name, a blank line, then the next entry of names while the last line in the text file is a blank line as well. So if we set the size to 1, then only the first entry, so, `[Smith, John]` should be added to a list and then returned. If the size was 2 then it should return two entries, so `[['Smith', 'John'], ['jeff', 'johnny']]`

**My attempt:**

```
def addToList(file, size):
    newList = []
    temp = []
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        # read each line in the file
        for line in f:
            # if the len of the newlist is less then the size then check
            # to see if its either a new line or not.
            if len(newList) < size:
                # if its not a new line than add the line to a temp list
                if line != "\n":
                    temp.append(line.strip())
                # if it is then that means we're going to move on
                # to a new entry so add this entry to the newList
                # and  reset the temp list.
                else:
                    newList.append(temp)
                    temp = []
    return newList
```

So I run `addToList("random.txt", 1)` I get `[['Smith', 'John']]` which is the correct result, since size = 1 = one entry. However, the problem with what I have is that if I set the size to be 2, so if I do `addToList("random.txt", 2)` I only get the list with the first entry of names rather then the 2 entries. So what I get is this: `[['Smith', 'John']]` rather than `[['Smith', 'John'], ['jeff', 'johnny']]` It seems like it doesn't read the last empty line, but how would I fix that? If anyone can help me out that would be really appreciated.

**Examples for clarification:**

```
Lets say text file is this:

Smith
John
emptyline
John
Smith
emptyline
Smith
John
emptyline
John
Jeff
emptyline

results should be:

addToList("random.txt", 1) -> [['Smith', 'John']] because size = 1 = # of entry = 1
addToList("random.txt", 2) -> [['Smith', 'John'], ['John', 'Smith']]
addToList("random.txt", 3) -> [['Smith', 'John'], ['John', 'Smith'], ['Smith', 'John']]
addToList("random.txt", 4) -> [['Smith', 'John'], ['John', 'Smith'], ['Smith', 'John'], ['John', 'Jeff']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do like the below,

```
with open('file') as f:
    fil = f.read()
    print([i.split('\n') for i in fil.split('\n\n') if i])
```

Output:

```
[['Smith', 'John'], ['Jeff', 'Johnny']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to build an accumulator that grabs each non-blank line, appending it to a result when it encounters a blank line.

```
def read_file(path):
    with open(path) as inf:
        result = []
        group = []
        for line in inf:
            line = line.strip()
            if not line: # blank line
                result.append(group)
                group = []
            else:
                group.append(line)
    return result
```

The another option is:

```
def read_file(path, groupsize):
    with open(path) as inf:
        while True:
            try:
                yield [next(inf).strip() for _ in range(groupsize)]
            except StopIteration:
                # EOF
                return
            next(inf) # skip the blank line
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Adam. If I were to run your second method with groupsize 1, I get the result: [['Smith'], [''], ['Johnny']] instead of [['Smith'], ['Johnny']] and lets say I were to add another entry to the textfile then if I were to put groupsize to 2 I get all three entries, so [['Smith', 'John'], ['Jeff', 'Johnny'], ['Jeff1', 'Johnny']] rather then [['Smith', 'John'], ['Jeff', 'Johnny']]. Is there a way I can fix that?